# NativeScript font size very small in preview

Tags: nativescript, font-size, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying out NativeScript for the first time, creating an iOS app based of what I currently have created in Angular for web. To preview the app I'm using the `ns preview` and I'm not sure if it's a preview bug or my configuration is wrong. When I first run it the font size of all elements is scaled down, then after I make a change it resets the font size to a correct size.

I don't use any units to define the font size, just numbers

```
Label {
  font-size: 14;
}
```

| Weird Font Size | Normal Font Size |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Weird Font Size] | [image: Normal Font Size] |

Should I just ignore it and deploy to the App Store or it's an issue and there is a way to fix it?